# How do i change the font color according to the decimal selected

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am trying to make a decimal calculator where people can choose infinite form. 
As an example , if i choose 1 the last digit will be highlighted(or add span in the last text and font-color:blue) , if i choose 2 the last 2 digit will be highlighted.

Problem i facing now is , it is an Input Box , so how do i make the function to select the digit from behind and add span in between them to make the font color different ?

What JQuery should i use ?

TQ

Comment: You haven't provided any code relevant to your issue. Refer to [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Tomanow can you give me a idea how to i use jquery to specific which font to change the color ? TQ

Comment: Please provide some code or fiddle that you've attempted.

Comment: @d_ominic http://jsfiddle.net/MRP5M/6/ this is my code. Now i need to make it wrap a span from the last word. if the globalnum is 1 means it wrap the last digit. if it is 2 it wraps the last 2 digit.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the style of the input value. Instead, you could create another element that will have populate as the input value changes (so that the input field would have the same value as that element's content) and then you can add spans, change colors, etc.

UPDATE

Here is a fully working version of what you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/MRP5M/45/

HTML

```
<input type="text" value="2" id="l" />
<input type="text" value="A really long string of content" id="t" />
<div id='output'></div>
```

JS

```
function update() {
    var str = $('input#t').val();
    var l = $('input#l').val();
    var s1 = str.substring(0, str.length - l);
    var s2 = str.substring(str.length - l);
    $('#output').html(s1 + '<span>' + s2 + '</span>');
}

$('input').on('keyup', function(){
    update();
})
```

UPDATE 2

http://jsfiddle.net/MRP5M/49/

Comment: jsfiddle.net/MRP5M/6 could you have a look in the code here ? Tq

Comment: Alright, here is something to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/MRP5M/41/  I've created an alert that breaks the string into two parts, depending on the var l (currently set to 2). Now you can use the two new strings and put them into two separate elements and apply different styling to each

Comment: I wrote you the full version.

Comment: i have made a code and used the string. but can't seems wrap it and how to prevent it that wont wrap beyond the decimal.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MRP5M/47/ here is my update !! just need to figure out to limit it not highlight beyond the decimal :)

Comment: So for 1234.56 you want to highlight 34 if the highlight is set to 2? Or 56?

Comment: 56 highlight will be done after the decimal. sorry if i confused you :)

Comment: You confused me a bit, yes. :)  So you want to highlight numbers only after the decimal, and having the value to control how many numbers will get highlighted? http://jsfiddle.net/MRP5M/48/

Comment: There is some problem with your new code. after decimal that 2 number could not be highlited

Comment: i mean if you type 2 decimal. it wont highlight

Comment: I've updated it, but please tell me: a) what number you typed, b) what length you typed, c) what should be highlighted (if it's wrong)

Comment: Typed : 123(without decimal) , Length : 2 , Nothing should be highlited